# Using a tabletop as a shelf?

Tags: strength, durability

I am wanting to install a shelf above a washer and dryer. Seems like a lot of the DIY videos involve buying 3/4 plywood and cutting it to size and then various other steps to take it from the rough state of plywood into a finished product. Most of the tools needed I don't even have, like a miter saw. I had the idea of possibly using a table top like the one shown below. It is 23.6"D x 59"W x 1.1"H, the exact measurements I need and it weighs 38 lb.

[https://www.amazon.com/VIVO-Universal-Standard-Adjustable-DESK-TOP60C/dp/B08WQ117GP/ref=sr_1_4?keywords=Wood%2BTable%2BTops&qid=1662932509&sr=8-4&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08WQ117GP)

[image: Tabletop]

The shelf would be placed in a corner. So one short side of the shelf would be floating while the other two would be supported. Considering that I would install appropriate 24 inch brackets that can hold 250lb each, spaced 16 inch apart is there anything that makes this a bad idea? Besides the fact that it is engineered wood, and would bubble if moisture remains on top for a long time?

Comment: If you're using shelf supports only 16" apart even if they didn't support the full depth this seems completely fine to me. I was all set to warn you that this material typically isn't very stiff but it's 1" thick and the unsupported spans are tiny by shelf standards, so there's little chance you'll get any sagging at all unless you massively overload your shelf with heavy items :-) It's impossible to predict how the stuff you'll get is actually made but the top *might* actually be basically waterproof, it's the edges and corners you'd need to concern yourself (so bear in mind when cleaning).

Comment: It seems entirely "do-able." Plywood isn't particularly waterproof either. Since this desktop is made out of particleboard, you might want to give it a waterproof finish like polyurethane or varnish to ensure that moisture/steam from the dryer, etc. doesn't deteriorate the edges/corners as Graphus mentions.

Answer (score 3):

> is there anything that makes this a bad idea?

As long as you provide sufficient support, considering that it's described as "solid particle board," it should work well enough. 24" does seem very deep for an overhead shelf, but if it's what you want, great.

That said, consider that $139 is a lot to pay for what amounts to a slab of particle board. A 4x8' sheet of melamine covered particle board costs less than a third of that, and you could get a piece of butcher block countertop in close to the size you need for [about $50 more](https://www.homedepot.com/p/HARDWOOD-REFLECTIONS-Unfinished-Alder-6-ft-L-x-25-in-D-x-1-5-in-T-Butcher-Block-Countertop-152574HDAL-74/308772504).